# Failed to load resource: Frame load interrupted

Tags: javascript, safari, xmlhttprequest, blob

I m trying to download zip file which is present in response of ajax call made using Blob, but I am getting error Failed to load resource: Frame load interrupted. It works in every browser except Safari. 
Here is my code:

```
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url + '?' + params, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Authorization', 'Token ' + $localStorage.token);
        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        xhr.onload = function(e) {
          if (200 <= this.status && this.status < 300) { // success
            var content = this.response;
            var anchor = document.createElement('a');
            var clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click');
            anchor.download = projectName + '.zip';
            var blob = new Blob([content], {type: 'application/zip'});
            anchor.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            anchor.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
          }
        };
        xhr.send();
```

Any suggerstions?